# cross domain reading data from browser storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jstorage

I am trying to store data with a unique ID into the browser's storage, from say `a.com` using jStorage and jQuery. I am then trying to read the data using the unique ID from, say `b.com`. But `jStorage.get('UniqueID')` is not working, and it's not showing the desired output.

Can anyone help me with reading browser storage cross-domain?

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/) has some information related to cross-domain storage. It offers "the basic technique of using an iframe to access another domain's `localStorage` object."