# Can we use IndexedDB between two pages on different domains?

Tags: indexeddb, access-control

I have created a IndexdDB object store in my one page (Let object store name is "ShopStore"). Now I want to open the same object store from a diffirent page. Is it possible?

My two web pages are on different domain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB) you can't do cross domain access to an indexedDB (for security reason, you don't want that another website modify your client database):

> IndexedDB follows a same-origin policy. So while you can access stored data within a domain, you cannot access data across different domains.

See also:

- [cross domain reading data from browser storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015022/cross-domain-reading-data-from-browser-storage)
- [Is it possible for a Chrome extension to access an IndexedDB database created by a specific domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453418/is-it-possible-for-a-chrome-extension-to-access-an-indexeddb-database-created-by)

Comment: **It is possible** if both domains work together. The page on a.example.com can embed an iframe on b.example.com. Both will have access to their own **separate** IndexedDB storage spaces. However, they can **communicate** via [**postMessage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) thus allowing them to give each other access to each others storage spaces.

Comment: @StijndeWitt Yes, but that's more of a special case since the ('main') domain is the same, only the subdomain changes.

Comment: Yes, it was not intended as a criticism of the answer, which simply is correct, just as a tip/suggestion for people looking for solutions.