# How do you delete all indexedDBs related to your domain on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, indexeddb

I have a page on my web app that should clear all offline data for the app, including the localStorage and all IndexedDBs.

My problem is on iOS8+ (Safari 8),`indexedDB.webkitGetDatabaseNames()` is not supported. My intention was to step through each database name and use `indexedDB.deleteDatabase()` to delete each database, but without knowing the names of the databases, this is impossible.

I suppose it would be naive to expect a .clear() similar to localStorage, but is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `webkitGetDatabaseNames` function is not part of the IndexedDB standard and that's why it's not supported on all browsers. And since you can only access databases that are created on the [same domain (same origin policy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874290/can-we-use-indexddb-objects-stores-between-two-pages/23874433#23874433), you can keep a list of databases that you've created and delete them when needed.